# Put content alongside h1

Tags: css

I want to add buttons beneath a `<h1>` tag, but don't know what CSS to use to make it so. The image below shows a likely scenario, with the "Main_Page" title and the buttons forming each part of a separate div. I tried using the `margin-top` property, but wish to know which other techniques can I use.

[image]

I used the following CSS for the buttons div, while nothing for the name div.

```
#wiki-page-head .buttons
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: right;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Provide minimal code example. Probably your Main_Page block has `float: left`. The you could either remove this `float: left`, or add `clear: both` of `clear: left` to buttons block.

Comment: A jsFiddle is the best way to share and demonstrate code problems.

Comment: Yes. Do you want, for instance, the h1 to be on top of the buttons, obsuring the buttons really?

Comment: See an example http://jsfiddle.net/RV5RS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <h1 style="display:inline;vertical-align:-3px;" >Ton titre</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <input type="button" value="Edit"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Discussion"></input>
        <input type="button" value="History"></input>
    </div>
```

With this code, you should get a result like that the image below, is that what you want ?
[image: Result]

Comment: I found the `display: inline` much better to use than having to define the margins. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @chrisportelli, thats not beneath, you mean side by side

Comment: @Starx : the image helped me ^^